# how to open a wizardpage using a toolbar button in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm doing a GUI Project which consists of a wizards and a
wizardpage. The wizardpage is created using the eclipse plugin 
**"org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage"**  I'm able to open the wizard using a toolbar button with the eclipse plugin 
**"org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog"** but i'm not able  to open the wizardpage with the same plugin.

Is there any other plugin for the
wizard page.    Can anyone help me in doing this?

Comment: You mean the wizard dialog opens, but there nothing in it ? You should post some relevant code of your wizard so we may help you.

Comment: @Baldrick i have two wizards followed by a wizard page,i m able to open the wizard.i should be able to open the wizard page directly..what code do u want to send me?either the code used to create the wizard page or the code to open the wizard page from the toolbar button?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want to do. A wizard page is inside a wizard, not after. Maybe look at these tutorials, you'll find some help: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWizards/article.html or http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JFaceWizards/index.html

Comment: @Baldrick i have to open a wizard page when a button in the toolbar is pressed?

Comment: @Baldrick i went through these tutorials but i did not get the solutions for the problem.there r two wizards followed by a wizard page.i need to directly access the wizard page without going through the wizards?Should i create a Dialog Page for the wizard Page to access directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot go to a specific wizard page unless it is the first page of a wizard.

To open a specific wizard - and not the "wizard chooser" - then add the `newWizardId` parameter to the menus definition...

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
         allPopups="false"
         locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
      <toolbar id="id.of..toolbar">
         <command commandId="org.eclipse.ui.newWizard">
            <parameter name="newWizardId" value="id.of.wizard" />
         </command>
      </toolbar>
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Comment: so should i create one more wizard page which is first page.then if i create it as the first page how to open it using a toolbar button.

Answer (score 3):

In your override **execute** method in the handler class (which extends the org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler),try the following code:

```
    IWizard wizard = new YourWizard();
    WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(), wizard);
    dialog.open();
```

;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
 public  void openWizard(String id) {
 // First see if this is a "new wizard".
 IWizardDescriptor descriptor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
   .getNewWizardRegistry().findWizard(id);
 // If not check if it is an "import wizard".
 if  (descriptor == null) {
   descriptor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getImportWizardRegistry()
   .findWizard(id);
 }
 // Or maybe an export wizard
 if  (descriptor == null) {
   descriptor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getExportWizardRegistry()
   .findWizard(id);
 }
 try  {
   // Then if we have a wizard, open it.
   if  (descriptor != null) {
     **IWizard wizard = descriptor.createWizard();**   
                                 **//here you can set the first show page**

     WizardDialog wd = new  WizardDialog(getStandardDisplay()
       .getActiveShell(), wizard);
     wd.setTitle(wizard.getWindowTitle());
     wd.open();
   }
 } catch  (CoreException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```